# When I log with admin FB-page user, I cannot do FB like to posts in that FB page?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

My android app requires FB login.

In in I get from the server a FB-postId.

The logged in user can do a Fb like to that post (which is always part of a FB page).

When I test the app I sometime log in as a page admin (admin via FB original web UI)

and then I cannot do the like.

I get this error:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 283, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#283) Require extended permission: manage_pages}, isFromCache:false}
```

when I log in as a non admin of that FB page, the like succeeds.

This is my FB code:

```
private void afterFacebookSessionReOpen(
                        final Offer currentOffer, Session session) {
                    // List<String> re = session.getPermissions();

                    Request request = new Request(
                            session,
                            takeFromPublicMacrosOrServer(currentOffer.fbPostId)
                                    + "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST,
                            new Request.Callback() {

                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(Response response) {


                                    // Request complete
                                    if (response.getError() == null) {
                                        UnlockRequestToServer unlockRequestToServer = new UnlockRequestToServer(
                                                mOffersListActivity,
                                                PublicMacros.TYPE_UNLOCK_FB_LIKE,
                                                currentOffer.fbPostId);

                                        // (4) unlock 4 - skip
                                        sendUnlockRequestToServer(
                                                unlockRequestToServer,
                                                currentLockView);
                                    } else {
                        ...
                            });
                    request.executeAsync();
                }
```

Comment: You are suppose to provide `manage_pages` permission to use and post on facebook pages. Make sure you have provided it.

Comment: but i don't want to post on the page, just do a "like" to an existing post in a page. And also why does this doesn't happen from a non-admin user?